# Computer stuck on bootloop

Tags: boot, windows-10, power-supply, power

So i've had my computer for about 7 - 12 months now and its been working perfectly fine i have an i7, asus Maximus vii, 890w power supply sad, hard drive and gtx 780.
Now the other day i was doing stuff and all of a sudden the PC just turned off out of now where (It was not that the power had been turned off). initially i thought the CPU might have over heated but i have water cooling that has been working for the time i've had the computer. But i waited a couple of hours then i tried turning the computer on and for literally 1 second it turned on the fans turned on but then it shutdown straight away there wasn't even a boot screen. 
So if anyone has any idea of whats going on with it please let me know, even the little things can sometimes help heaps.

A solution that was recommended and worked for a while but no longer works is: Unplug the power cable, hold down power button for 30 seconds then release, plug power cable back in and try again.

Comment: Open the case and have a look on the motherboard.  Can you see a battery or a button cell on it ?

Comment: Yea i can see the battery, do you think i should replace it?

Comment: Silicon Dies randomly sometimes, I'm assuming you are overclocking with the water cooling? Did you mess with voltages for CPU or Memory? Resetting BIOS/Firmware may help if a brownout or supply issue caused the eeprom to get corrupt, but to me the symptoms sound like something died. Most modern motherboards can detect firmware corruption and boot into a well defined state, what you are experiencing sounds like a hard HALT on boot, which is typically a damaged component

Comment: No i didn't try to overclock the cpu but last time this happened all i had to do was hold down the power button for 30 seconds and then turn it on and it would work but when it turned on it did say "Failed to overclock" or something similar to that when i actually never tried to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Open the case and have a look on the motherboard. Can you see a battery or a button cell on it ?

If there is, replace it.  You may need to initialise the bios afterwards.

EDIT :  On older PCs, the BIOS settings are kept alive in CMOS (low power) memory with a battery.  This keeps things such as hard disk spec, ports, what boots first.  The battery also power the RTC (Real Time Clock).

Comment: Ok thank you, ill go buy one of those battery's and ill inform you if it worked.

Comment: "asus Maximus vii" has **UEFI** not BIOS firmware

Comment: Yea edit: can't find the bios battery so what do i do there?

Comment: Do you mean that you are unable to find a replacement ?  I am sure that someone will have stock.  Otherwise note down the battery's voltage and find another one of an identical voltage.  Without looking the board and connector etc, you may have to solder it in (carefully).

Comment: @Ramhound, I did not know that, however their website still says "USB UEFI BIOS "

Comment: @TomDickson, I searched for images of the motherboard, but I can't find any decent ones. But it does have a CLR_CMOS button, so the battery is definitely your problem.